# Is there a way to make a browser (userscript code) interact with another program, like a macro program (like JitBit)? How?

Tags: macros, tampermonkey, userscripts

Hello dear programmers and code professionals,

As someone who knows next to nothing about code or coding, I humbly come before you seeking advice:

There is a server that is accessed using the browser, and files are uploaded to it. To claim these files, a user (me) has to click some buttons and check some boxes. A friend wrote a script for me using tampermonkey, but he said that since the server doesn't have an API, all the script can do is refresh the interface every 0.5 seconds and play a sound when a new file is added. I had to set up a macro (using JitBit Macro) to click the buttons and check the boxes, but I have to activate it manually after the sound plays and that just seems silly.

Is there a way to make the browser click buttons and check boxes on the server when a new file is uploaded? Or make it activate the macro, which is an external program? Or even a way to automate the entire process, start to finish, with a piece of code, or an app, or a third party software? Preferably one which I can command to do or not do stuff based on the file parameters, like name, size or keywords?

I thank each and every one of you in advance for your advice, internet friends.

Edit: anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Your Tampermonkey script can check the boxes and click the buttons on the web page. No API is required. If the existing TM script can detect when new files are added (how does it do that?), then it should also be able to detect when the buttons appear, and once they exist, to click them. Similarly, your existing TM script can be modified to detect, identify and click checkboxes as well.

For more assistance, we would need to see what the DOM looks like. The DOM is the living HTML of the page - where buttons and checkboxes appear and disappear. In Google Chrome, you can view the DOM by Right-Clicking and choosing "Inspect", or by pressing F12.

If you can identify the button(s) you need to click in the DOM, we can guide you and your friend in how to watch for them to appear and to click them. We also would need to know in what order they must be clicked, and what makes each one appear (*i.e. After clicking the button with id="myButt", three checkboxes appear. Here is the HTML for those checkboxes...*)

If this answer meets your needs, I suggest closing out this question (by choosing a correct answer) and creating a new question when you are ready to show the HTML for the button you want clicked and ask for specific details about how to do that. The more of the DOM we see (*i.e. related to the buttons and how to find them starting at the `<body>` tag*), the better we will be able to assist. However, we must ***understand*** the task, so please be very detailed (point form) in your description of what makes each button/checkbox appear, and the order they must be clicked.

As for making the browser signal your JitBit program that the buttons are ready to click, ask your friend to change the tab title and then tell JitBit to watch for that Window to appear. To change a tab title:

```
document.title = 'GoJitBitGo';
```

I use both AutoIT and WinBatch to automate many desktop tasks and I've used that method frequently to trigger a WinBatch script to perform some wonders when signalled by a web page.